# How to route traffic of docker bridge interface via a VPN interface

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface, routing, vpn

I have a VPN interface `nordlynx`, default interface `ens5` and a docker bridge interface `br-83e694bd09ad`. Currently, the `nordlynx` interface doesn't have any traffic being routed through it, however doing `curl --interface nordlynx https://ifconfig.io` does work and sends the request through the VPN network (sending back the VPN server's IP address), while a simple `curl https://ifconfig.io` sends the request directly via `ens5` (showing the server's actual IP).

What I need to achieve is to somehow send all of the traffic comming from/to that docker interface over the `nordlynx` interface (to make the docker containers using this bridge only able to access the internet via the VPN), instead of it going directly thorugh the default `ens5`. However the rest of the "regular" traffic on the server should keep using the `ens5` interface as usual, only the docker traffic should be routed (I need anyone to still be able to reach the server's exposed ports, such as SSH, and the server to communicate with other devices using it's real IP - i.e. not going through the VPN).

From my research, it seems that docker itself doesn't have any easy config option I could use to achieve this, so instead I was hoping I could use regular linux routing or iptables rules somehow. However I don't know have that much experience here and I wasn't able to find any guides on how to achieve this kind of configuration.

This is the current output of `ip addr show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:1b:b3:94:71:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s5
    altname eni-03a0757ebcb70f7cd
    altname device-number-0
    inet 172.31.34.89/20 metric 512 brd 172.31.47.255 scope global dynamic ens5
       valid_lft 2072sec preferred_lft 2072sec
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:eb:b8:73:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
42: br-0c64a34b621d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:a4:56:d1:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-0c64a34b621d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
45: br-83e694bd09ad: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:48:a7:8b:ba brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.6.0.1/16 brd 10.6.255.255 scope global br-83e694bd09ad
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
54: nordlynx: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8921 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.5.0.2/32 scope global nordlynx
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is `ip route show` output:

```
default via 172.31.32.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
10.6.0.0/16 dev br-83e694bd09ad proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1 linkdown
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-0c64a34b621d proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
172.31.0.2 via 172.31.32.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
172.31.32.0/20 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
172.31.32.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
```

Output of `ip -details link show dev nordlynx`:

```
55: nordlynx: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8921 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/none  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 2147483552
    wireguard addrgenmode none numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

Output of `ip rule`:

```
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Output of `ip route show table local`:

```
local 10.5.0.2 dev nordlynx proto kernel scope host src 10.5.0.2
local 10.6.0.1 dev br-83e694bd09ad proto kernel scope host src 10.6.0.1
broadcast 10.6.255.255 dev br-83e694bd09ad proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1 linkdown
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
local 172.19.0.1 dev br-0c64a34b621d proto kernel scope host src 172.19.0.1
broadcast 172.19.255.255 dev br-0c64a34b621d proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
local 172.31.34.89 dev ens5 proto kernel scope host src 172.31.34.89
broadcast 172.31.47.255 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.34.89
```

Output of `ip route show table main`:

```
default via 172.31.32.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
10.6.0.0/16 dev br-83e694bd09ad proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1 linkdown
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-0c64a34b621d proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
172.31.0.2 via 172.31.32.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
172.31.32.0/20 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
172.31.32.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.34.89 metric 512
```

Output of `ip route show table default`:

```
Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist.
Dump terminated
```

Comment: @A.B I've edited the question and included the outputs from mentioned commands. I didn't run `nft list ruleset`, as I don't seem to even have the `nft` command. (Although I do have `iptables-nft` command.)

Comment: What makes this so complex? @A.B Can you think of some alternative to what I'm trying to do that would achieve the same?